# How to get mysql row count using JSON parsing onto Android TextView?

Tags: php, android, mysql, json

I have a php file that returns a single number (i.e. 360). How can I get that number to appear in my android textview. I am able to do this with arrays that look like this:

```
{"success":1,"message":"Post Available!","posts":[{"name":"John Smith","id":"1"}, ...]}
```

but how can I do it with just a single number.

Here is the php:

```
<?php

include('connect.php');

$gettotal=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM records");
totalrecords=mysql_num_rows($gettotal);
echo json_encode($totalrecords);

?>
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

A number is STILL going to be just a number after your json_encode() it.

```
$num = 42;
$json = json_encode($num);
echo "$num / $json"
```

will just output `42 / 42` - there will be no practical difference between the two.

Comment: I got the number to output, but how I need help with the Java code to get it into the TextView.